# width of colorbox

Tags: colorbox

I was wondering if there's a way to set the length of a colorbox. For example:

[image]

As you can see, the right edge of the box is a bit too much (and the left edge too), and I just want the edges to exactly fit the text.

The two right square brackets have too much of a space in between them (looks like ] ]),but my hope would be something more like ]]).

This is my current code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}

[\textsubscript{CP\textsubscript{2}} Ming4zai2 \colorbox{shadecolor}{[\textsubscript{CP} laa3 [\textsubscript{TP} \textit{t} zau2-zo2]}]

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help improve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can set `\fboxsep` to `0pt` and then increase the height of the material inside manually if you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{black!15}{[\textsubscript{CP} laa3 [\textsubscript{TP} \textit{t}
zau2-zo2]\strut}]

\bigskip

\colorbox{black!15}{[\textsubscript{CP} laa3 [\textsubscript{TP} \textit{t}
zau2-zo2]\vrule height 4mm depth 2.5mm width 0mm}]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `adjustbox` as a replacement for `\colorbox` and use the `margin` and `bgcolor` keys to get the frame separation only on top and bottom but not (or less) on left and right.

The following sets the left/right margin to 0pt and the top/bottom margin to the same as with `\colorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.85}

\newcommand\mycolorbox[1]{\adjustbox{margin=0pt {\fboxsep},bgcolor=#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}

[\textsubscript{CP\textsubscript{2}} Ming4zai2 \mycolorbox{shadecolor}{[\textsubscript{CP} laa3 [\textsubscript{TP} \textit{t} zau2-zo2]}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A Ti*k*Zy alternative to David <s>Koala</s> Purton's nice answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\tikzmarknode[fill=gray!30,inner xsep=-0.1em]{X}{[\textsubscript{CP} laa3 [\textsubscript{TP} \textit{t} zau2-zo2]}]
\end{document}
```

[image]